# Any algorithm for generating layout in a document?

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, pdf-generation

First of all, I apologize my bad English.

I want to generate document image set which of layouts are randomly assigned in image.
Specifically, the size of paper is 2000*1500. And each layout's (paragraph, figures, etc) width and height should be 300 * 500 as minimum.

[image]

There's no rule on generating but what I only want is it should look like real "document" (like paper PDF). Attached drawing depicts what I'm thinking about.

[oh yes, I do think this pic is horrible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBv3h.png)

*p.s.) Sorry but I don't want to split paper two side so make it easy. Just wondered how it makes possible!
Code in Python 3 most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Since i said i don't wanna split two sides in layout, I tried to split width and height with randomly chosen number of area. And it did looks good.

[image]

Comment: can you please share the code with us?
This is very interesting question!

Thanks a lot

Comment: @taga Hi, I updated the result image example. If it matches your needs, tell me again, please!

Comment: It looks good. I have similar problem., I want to generate layout based on images and text. If you can share your code, it would be great

Comment: https://github.com/BaeKwangho/PIMGenerator 
Here's the repository. I think you can check `layout_process` folder to find algorithm